# Can we reset security token using SFDX CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, security-token

I'm trying to find a way to reset default scratch org user's Security Token via CLI. Is that even possible?

Comment: One way i know generate password for scratch org and then login and do a token reset

Comment: Yeah, that's a manual way, I am looking for a script compatible CLI option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating a password for the user (force:user:password:generate) should automatically send you an email with the security token. There's no separate command for this in the CLI. You would use the UI if you want to reset the token without resetting the password.

Comment: I have reset my password using below command but  have not received any email with security token. Am I missing something?

sfdx force:user:password:generate --targetusername test-skf2aegzbtzi@example.com

Comment: @Swetha The token should have been sent by email. Regardless, if you haven't received it, you can manually reset it from the Setup screen.

Comment: @sfdxfox Resetting password via UI (My Username> my settings> Reset password)too does not send me the security token.